# Parse-Server Cloud Code Query Doesn't Return All Columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I have setup Parse-Server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk by following [this](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk) guide. I've then written a cloud-code function which fetches a single record from a specific class/collection. The collection contains about 20 columns. However, the object fetched as a result of the query contains only about 8 columns. I've made sure the record does have data in the columns which are missed by the query. Am I missing something here or is it some limitation in Parse? Is there any way to force Parse to fetch these columns?

```
Parse.Cloud.define('confirmAppointment', function(request, response) {
    var staffId = request.params.staffId;
    var appointmentId = request.params.appointmentId;

    var appointmentRequest = Parse.Object.extend("AppointmentRequest");
    appointmentRequest.id = appointmentId;
    appointmentRequest.staffId = staffId;

    var query = new Parse.Query(appointmentRequest);

    query.first({
        useMasterKey: true,
        success: function(appointment) {
            if (appointment) {

                // these fields are not found in the fetched appointment object
                // they do exist however in mongodb
                var requesterUserId = appointment.get("requesterUserId");
                var staffUserId = appointment.get("staffUserId");
                var staffName = appointment.get("staffNameEn");
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Are the missing columns pointer types to other objects?

Comment: No. Some of them are string types, and some are numeric types.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some typos in your code (the construction of the query part). Try this instead:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('confirmAppointment', function(req, res) {
  var staffId = req.params.staffId;
  var appointmentId = req.params.appointmentId;

  var query = new Parse.Query("AppointmentRequest");
  query.equalTo('objectId', appointmentId);
  query.equalTo('staffId', staffId);

  query.first({
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(appointment) {
      res.success(appointment.get("requesterUserId"));
    },
    error: function(err) {
      res.error(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, the query indeed had some typos, which I later fixed. But the real issue was that I had not clicked the Finalize button in Parse database migration wizard.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that when i did migration of data from Parse to my mongolab hosted MongoDB instance, I did not click 'Finalize' button in Parse migration wizard. That was intentional, as Parse was warning me that clicking Finalize would make the migration permanent and I would no longer be able to get back to the Parse managed database. On the other hand, I could see that all the data was successfuly migrated to mongolab, and technically it should have been enough to have my AWS hosted parse server work on this new database without any issue. But somehow, clicking "Finalize" button in Parse did some magic (I still dont understand what it could be) and my queries started returning the expected results.

I was able to reproduce the same issue when migrating to Heroku as well, so i was sure it had nothing to do with AWS.

Hope this would help someone.